# iOS App Name does not appear completly

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am publishing an app but something weird happens. when i publish it, Its name which is "InsideDigs" appears to be Inside... When its published although when i compile it it appears normally.

[image: icon name]

It appears like that only when its on Test flight. Any ideas why this is happening. I saw several apps that have longer names and appear completely.

Thank you

Comment: just guessing, maybe the presence of the dot leave not enough space to display the label. What happen when you open the app for the first time and  the dot is removed?

Comment: It won't happen when app is released, no worries. The dot means that the app is not signed with production certificates or something like that

Comment: @Frane Poljak I Dont mean the red dot :) I mean the three dots after "Inside" :)

Comment: I know, but the red dot is the reason why the whole name is not displayed

Answer (score 3):

The red dot is a character that is added to the name when using Testflight.
So the name becomes too long to be displayed and iOS shortens the name and ads the three dots at the end to show the user that the name was shortened.